# Making a pressure mapping sensor

Tags: sensor

I am trying to design and prototype a pressure mapping sensor to measure the force between two surfaces.

I prefer to use piezoresistive materials. I am thinking to use 4x4 cell; also I should try to use flexible material not to be broken under applied force.

Can anyone guide me or inform me of possible references, please?

Comment: Is doing a little litography an option?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information? How big is it? How small a pressure change must it sense? What is the maximum pressure it must survive? Does it need to register 4x4, or 16 distinct positions that pressure is applied, or does it need to detect an even finer resolution?

Comment: it is a small area - 40*40 mm sq. The applied force  to the surface is between 0 and 20 N.-( with 0.2N Resolution)( the 4*4 cell can be different but that is what I think can be useful for the design

Comment: That is very useful, however I am still unclear, are you looking to get 16 distinct values from the pressure senor? Also, please add that extra information to your question, so that it makes sense without needing the comments. stackexchange is more like a wiki than a forum. You might like to look at the [Help Centre](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) to better understand the way stackexchange is intended to work.

Answer (score 1):

Sensitronics sells an [FSR matrix sensor array](http://www.sensitronics.com/products-thru-mode-matrix-array.php). FSR is in fact a piezoreistive material. It's 10x16, so bigger than your needs but good to consider.

Answer (score 0):

This integrated [sensor](http://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-force-sensors-fss-smt-product-sheet_008181-3-en.pdf) seems like a perfect match. Although placing them with \$10\, \mathrm{mm}\$ spacing might be a challenge.